# "Import Error" with Transporter App status mode

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I am reviewing Apples transporter app to automate Auto Renewable subscriptions configuration as we need to do the same on an internal portal along side AppStoreConnect. While I was experimenting with a sample app, I created a dummy IAP profile in a metadata.xml file and uploaded it (Transporter `upload` mode).

The transporter's response was successful upload, but the AppStore Connect does not reflect the auto-renewable IAP being created.

Also, calling the transporter app's `status` mode outputs something called `Import Error`. Not sure what does it mean and how to rectify or debug further.

```
<upload_status apple_identifier="***" 
    vendor_identifier="com.demo.aaa.starter">
    <content_status_info itunes_connect_status="">
        <store_status not_on_store="N/A" on_store="N/A" ready_for_store="N/A"/>
        <tickets/>
    </content_status_info>
    <upload_status_info created="2019-06-11 08:55:52" status="Import Error"/>
    </upload_status>
</itunes_transporter>
```

Here are the details of how I am using the transporter:

- The app I am using is a sample app, not published on App Store. This is primarily for experimentation with other production apps.
- I am using the default transporter app installed with Xcode on MacOS.
- I am using the metadata.xml only for the confiuration of auto-renewable subscriptions and nothing else.

Here is my `metadata.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="software5.11">
    <provider>DUMMYPROVIDER</provider>
    <!--<team_id>A9B8C7D6E5</team_id>-->
    <software>
        <vendor_id>com.demo.aaa.starter</vendor_id>
        <software_metadata>
            <in_app_purchases>
                <subscription_group name="AutoUploadTestSG">
                    <locales>
                        <locale name="en-US">
                            <title>Test Subscription Group</title>
                            <app_name>Test App</app_name>
                        </locale>
                    </locales>
                    <in_app_purchase>
                        <product_id>com.demo.aaa.starter.p1</product_id>
                        <reference_name>Product1</reference_name>
                        <type>auto-renewable</type>
                        <duration>1 Month</duration>
                        <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                        <rank>1</rank>
                        <prices>
                            <price>
                                <territory>US</territory>
                                    <tier>5</tier>
                            </price>
                            <price>
                                <territory>GH</territory>
                                    <tier>5</tier>
                            </price>
                            <price>
                                <territory>KH</territory>
                                    <tier>5</tier>
                            </price>
                            <price>
                                <territory>ES</territory>
                                    <tier>5</tier>
                            </price>

                        <!-- Additional territories here -->
                        </prices>
                        <!-- <products>
                            <product>
                                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                                <wholesale_price_tier>3</wholesale_price_tier>
                            </product>
                        </products> -->
                        <locales>
                            <locale name="en-US">
                                <title>Product 1</title>
                                <description>This product provides access to product #1</description>
                            </locale>
                        </locales>
                        <review_screenshot>
                            <file_name>screenshot-01.png</file_name>
                            <size>107477</size>
                            <checksum type="md5">0cdbb1a31bd501f0425e0c30622a04da</checksum>
                        </review_screenshot>
                        <review_notes>Some notes for the reviewer.</review_notes>
                    </in_app_purchase>
                    <in_app_purchase>
                        <product_id>com.demo.aaa.starter.p2</product_id>
                        <reference_name>Product2</reference_name>
                        <type>auto-renewable</type>
                        <duration>3 Months</duration>
                        <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
                        <rank>2</rank>
                        <prices>
                            <price>
                                <territory>US</territory>
                                    <tier>5</tier>
                            </price>
                            <price>
                                <territory>GH</territory>
                                    <tier>8</tier>
                            </price>
                            <price>
                                <territory>KH</territory>
                                    <tier>8</tier>
                            </price>
                            <price>
                                <territory>ES</territory>
                                    <tier>8</tier>
                            </price>

                        </prices>                       
                        <locales>
                            <locale name="en-US">
                                <title>Product 2</title>
                                <description>This product provides access to product #2</description>
                            </locale>
                        </locales>
                        <review_screenshot>
                            <file_name>screenshot-02.png</file_name>
                            <size>103040</size>
                            <checksum type="md5">2aded6313ed9e6ddeef9152d141027c8</checksum> 
                        </review_screenshot>
                        <review_notes>Some notes for the reviewer.</review_notes>
                    </in_app_purchase>
                </subscription_group>
            </in_app_purchases>
        </software_metadata>
    </software>
</package>
```

P.S: The actual file has configurations for all 155 territories. I have excluded most here for brevity.

Comment: Did you first download the package and then edited it or did you try to create it from scratch?

Comment: I did create it from scratch, there was a problem with one of the images. I later got an email mentioning the same. On rectifying the error, I was able to upload successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the resolution of one of the images that were uploaded.

How did I get to know that?
Well, I received an email from AppStoreConnect stating the reason.

On rectifying the error and uploading it again, I was able to create the IAP in AppStoreConnect.

The status now looks like this:

```
<upload_status apple_identifier="***" vendor_identifier="com.demo.aaa.starter">
    <content_status_info itunes_connect_status="">
        <store_status not_on_store="N/A" on_store="N/A" ready_for_store="N/A"/>
        <tickets/>
    </content_status_info>
    <upload_status_info created="2019-06-11 08:55:52" status="Imported"/>
</upload_status>
```